# How to delete existing servers on PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

How to delete existing servers on PhpStorm? It seems that it is not even possible to delete the wrong ones.

Comment: And what do you mean by "server" exactly? Screenshot please.

Comment: When you open PhpStorm and you choose 'Create New Project from Existing Files', then 'Web server is on remote, files are accessible via FTP'. After naming the project, you have to specify the server. The list keep getting bigger and it is not possible to delete even the wrong ones.

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment`. Please note that most (if not all) of those entries will be Shared entries (seen to all projects) and therefore potentially can be used by more than one project. It's better to make them project-specific ("Visible only for this project" check box)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those "servers" are deployment entries and they can be managed at `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment`.

Please note that most (if not all) of those entries most likely (in your case, of course) will be **shared entries** (seen by all projects; it's default and only option in older PhpStorm versions) and therefore potentially can be used by more than one project. It's better if you go trough each existing project and **make them project-specific** (`Visible only for this project` check box -- if you do not have such option then you are using quite old PhpStorm version).